# Find the maximum value of an algebraic expression.

Tags: contest-math

The question is:

> Determine the maximum value of $a, b, c$ from the following system of quadratic equations.
> $$\frac{4a^2}{1+4a^2}=b$$
> $$\frac{4b^2}{1+4b^2}=c$$
> $$\frac{4c^2}{1+4c^2}=a$$

I haven't an idea on how to do this, and my attempts led to a dead end. Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You could start by first pluggin in the third equation into the first one, i.e. instead of writing $a$, write $\frac{4c^2}{1+4c^2}$, and use the second equation to subsitute $c$ by the expression for $b$. This leaves you with just an equation for $b$, which then can be used in order to calculate $a$, $b$.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray that will lead to something like $b {{\left( 2 b-1\right) }^{2}} \left( 5696 {{b}^{6}}+1600 {{b}^{5}}+496 {{b}^{4}}+96{{b}^{3}}+28{{b}^{2}}+4 b+1\right)=0$ with the obvious real roots of $0$ and $\frac12$ (as a double root).  The final term is clearly positive for non-negative $b$ (in fact for all $b$ but that is not needed) so the maximum real root is $\frac12$.  Similarly for $a$ and $c$, and $a=b=c=\frac12$ is a solution and so the maximal real one

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{4a^2}{1+4a^2}=b \wedge \frac{4b^2}{1+4b^2}=c \Rightarrow c = \frac{64 a^4}{80 a^4 + 8 a^2 + 1}$, while $\frac{4c^2}{1+4c^2}=a$.
Now, we substitute the last one into the second term of $c = \frac{64 a^4}{80 a^4 + 8 a^2 + 1}$, so we finally get $c(2c-1)=0 \Rightarrow c \in \{0,\frac{1}{2}\}$ and hence, $max\{0,\frac{1}{2}\}=0.5$.
Thus, by symmetrical construction, you can easily show that $max\{a\}=max\{b\}=max\{c\}=max\{0,\frac{1}{2}\}=0.5$ (and similarly $min\{a\}=min\{b\}=min\{c\}=min\{0,\frac{1}{2}\}=0$).

Comment: How do you get $c(2c-1)=0$ rather than $c {{\left( 2 c-1\right) }^{2}} \left( 5696 {{c}^{6}}+1600 {{c}^{5}}+496 {{c}^{4}}+96{{c}^{3}}+28{{c}^{2}}+4 c+1\right)=0$?

Comment: Let $c$ belong to the set $\mathbb{R}$ by hypothesis.
By substitution, we get $c = \frac{16384 c^8}{22784 c^8 + 1280 c^6 + 224 c^4 + 16 c^2 + 1}$ which has only two real solutions (i.e., $c=0$ and $c=\frac{1}{2}$), thus $2c^2-c=0$ (Q.E.D.)

Answer (score 3):

A clear solution is $a = b = c = 0$. Assuming that is not the case, one can rewrite the equations as:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{b} = 1 + \frac{1}{4a^2}; \quad \frac{1}{c} = 1 + \frac{1}{4b^2}; \quad  \frac{1}{a} = 1 + \frac{1}{4c^2}.
\end{align*}
On adding them all up, we obtain,
\begin{align*}
3 + \frac{1}{4a^2} + \frac{1}{4b^2} + \frac{1}{4c^2}   & = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \\
\implies \frac{1}{4a^2} -\frac{1}{a} + 1 + \frac{1}{4b^2} -\frac{1}{b} + 1 + \frac{1}{4c^2} -\frac{1}{c} + 1 & = 0\\
\left(\frac{1}{2a} - 1\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2b} - 1\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2c} - 1\right)^2 & = 0.
\end{align*}
The only solution to the above equation is that all the terms within the brackets are $0$, which yields us $a = b = c = 1/2$.

Comment: My answer below includes it, indeed. Anyway, I think that the search is over, since we have that $a=0 \Rightarrow b=0 \Rightarrow c=0$, whereas $a=0.5 \Rightarrow b=0.5 \Rightarrow c=0.5$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @JohnOmielan. Updated the solution.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Here's another approach.

Define $\ f:\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\ $ by
$$
f(x)\eqdef\frac{4x^2}{1+4x^2}\ .
$$
If $\ x_f\ $ is a fixed point of $\ f\ $ (that is, $\ f(x_f)=x_f\ $) then $\ a=$$\,b=$$\,c=$$\,x_f\ $ is a solution for the three equations.  One fixed point of $\ f\ $ is obviously $\ x_f=0\ $, and any *non-zero* fixed point, $\ x_f\ $, of $\ f\ $ must satisfy
$$
\frac{4x_f}{1+4x_f^2}=1\ ,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
(2x_f-1)^2=0\ .
$$
Thus $\ x_f=0\ $ and $\ x_f=\frac{1}{2}\ $ are the only fixed points of $\ f\ $.

If $\ a,b,c\ $ satisfy the three equations then they must each be fixed points of $\ f^3\ $.  But since
$$
f(x)-x=\frac{-x\big(2x-1\big)^2}{1+4x^2}<0
$$
for all non-negative $\ x\ne0,\frac{1}{2}\ $, then $\ f^3(x)<x\ $ also, for all non-negative $\ x\ne0,\frac{1}{2}\ $.  Therefore $\ f^3\ $ has no other fixed points than those of $\ f\ $, and $\ a=b=c=0\ $ and $\ a=b=c=\frac{1}{2}\ $ are the only solutions of the three equations.

Comment: The observation that $f(x) - x \leq 0 $ is crucial, and you might want to highlight that instead of making the focus just on fixed points.